# ошибка синтаксиса PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');

try {
$likesomeonegonnausethis = $_FILES['fupl']['tmp_name'];
$query = ('LOAD DATA INFILE :tfile INTO TABLE info FIELDS TERMINATED BY `^` ENCLOSED BY `"` LINES TERMINATED BY `\n` IGNORE 1 ROWS');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(['tfile' => $likesomeonegonnausethis]);
header('location:'.$weblocalurl.'/test');
} catch(PDOException $e) {
        $tm = $e->getMessage();
        header('location:'.$weblocalurl.'&error=Загрузка не удалась&errorreal='.$tm.'');
}

?>
```

загружаю файл, и пытаюсь извлечь данные из него в mysql. Первый раз такое делаю, не знаю где косяк может быть.

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` on this server.

Comment: $query = ("LOAD DATA INFILE :tfile INTO info FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS"); не помогло

Comment: каков теперь текст ошибки, или что-там? у меня вообще подозрение есть, что имя файла не получится задать параметром (:

Comment: текст ошибки не меняется никак

Comment: Если после того как вы убрали из запроса все обратные кавычки, и вам до сих пор выдается ошибка про обратную кавычку, значит ошибка в другом запросе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71779/discussion-on-question-by-paul-wall---pdo).